# Why are enemies so treacherous?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On many, many occasions in Skyrim, I fight an enemy and get them to low health. At this point, by far the most common thing they say is:

> No more! I yield! I yield!

I have, of course, learned better. But originally I figured "eh, what the hell, I've already pickpocketed him for everything, I'll let him live". As soon as he'd recovered enough to stand, he attacked me again (so I cut his head off).

Point is, are there any enemies that will actually yield when defeated (excluding Brawls), or is there really no honour among bandits?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from dialogue-initiated brawls and specially-scripted scenes (the only one that comes to mind is the moth priest in Dawnguard), nobody will actually yield and stop fighting during combat.